# Curvefield disappeared in unity 2017.1 version

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

After I wrote an `EditorGUILayout.Curvefield("curve", new AnimationCurve());` in `OnInspectorGUI` function in my custom editor script for my custom scriptable object, it doesn't appear in Inspector. But if I change the code to `EditorGUILayout.Curvefield("curve", null);`. There will be a curve field but can't edit in the curve editing window.
How can I change my code to make the curve field work? 
Or this is a bug of unity?

Answer (score 1):

```
EditorGUILayout.Curvefield("curve", new AnimationCurve());
```

This will create a **readonly** `AnimationCurve` every time OnInspectorGUI is called.

```
EditorGUILayout.Curvefield("curve", null);
```

What's the point of a null curve? This is completely wrong.

---

Correct usage of [`EditorGUILayout.CurveField`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.CurveField.html):

MyScript.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
public class MyScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AnimationCurve myCurve = AnimationCurve.Linear(0, 0, 10, 10);
}
```

Editor/MyScriptEditor.cs

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;    
[CustomEditor(typeof(MyScript))]
public class MyScriptEditor : Editor
{
    void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        var myScript = (MyScript)target;
        EditorGUILayout.CurveField("curve", myScript.myCurve);
    }
}
```

Then the result is:
[image: result]

It is editable.